# how to remove single quotes inside IN condition cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I m trying to pass comma separated values inside IN condition in cakephp 3 but it gets values with single quotes inside brackets ('12,18').

Please suggest me how to remove this.

**Expected output (12,18)**

Below is my code

```
public function checkPermission(){
        $userId = $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User.id');
        $arodta = TableRegistry::get('Aros');
        $Arosdata = $arodta->find()->where(['foreign_key' => $userId])->first()->toArray();
        if(!empty($Arosdata)){
            $aroId = $Arosdata['parent_id'];
            $aroAcodata = TableRegistry::get('ArosAcos');
            $arocodata = $aroAcodata->find()->where(['aro_id =' => $aroId]);   
            if(!empty($arocodata)) {
                foreach ($arocodata as $data){ 
                    $acoId[] = $data['aco_id'];
                }
                if(!empty($acoId)){
                    $acoData = implode(',',$acoId);
                    $acosName = TableRegistry::get('Acos');
                    $arac = $acosName->find()->where(['id IN' => $acoData]);
                    sql($arac);exit;                                           
                }
            }
        }                         
    }
```

**My Array data**

```
$acoId[] = 

    Array
    (
        [0] => 12
        [1] => 18
    )
```

**I am getting output like**

```
SELECT 
  Acos.id AS `Acos__id`, 
  Acos.parent_id AS `Acos__parent_id`, 
  Acos.model AS `Acos__model`, 
  Acos.foreign_key AS `Acos__foreign_key`, 
  Acos.alias AS `Acos__alias`, 
  Acos.lft AS `Acos__lft`, 
  Acos.rght AS `Acos__rght` 
FROM 
  acos Acos 
WHERE 
  id in ('12,18')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cakephp you can directly pass array for IN clause instead imploding it with comma. Use $acoId array in your query:

```
$arac = $acosName->find()->where(['id IN' => $acoId]);
```

Comment: My array comes with output like Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 18
)..but when i try to pass directly array inside IN query..it only gets first value not all values from array..

Comment: You do not need to worry about array indexing. It will automatically get the data. If you are not getting the result then there may be some other error.  You can try it with  static values like $acosName->find()->where(['id IN' => [12, 18]]);